# Angular material mat-button-toggle-group default value not set when using strings

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
<div class="navigation">
<mat-button-toggle-group class="button-toggle" 
[(ngModel)]="langSelected"
(change)="onToggleGroupChange($event)" [value]="langSelected">
  <mat-button-toggle value="en">{{ 'header.english'| translate }}</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="sv">{{ 'header.svenska'| translate }}</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>
```

[value]="sv" is not working properly or not at all. Somehow when using [value] ="langSelected" causes strange problem, so that when changing the language three times, the button group is not working any more, onToggleGroupChange is not called at all after three clicks. langSelected  is initialized on onInit to sv. So the main problem is how to set default value for mat-button-toggle-group when using strings instead of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

try removing the [value]="langSelected" use the [(ngModel)] only instead and use (ngModelChange) instead of (change)

Comment: When I replaced change --> ngModelChange the whole toggle button did not work at all anymore. I did take the value off before because toggle buttons stopped to work after changing the languages three times :D Thanks for answer!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).